# Include scheduled ( future ) posts in WordPress post navigation ( previous_post_link, next_post_link )

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is this possible? How can i change the query for adjacent posts and add 'post_status=future' to display next and previous posts for scheduled ones?

I suppose i should use some kind of filter, but could someone show me how? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`previous_post_link` uses `adjacent_post_link` which in turn uses `get_adjacent_post` which contains a SQL query string filter called `get_{$adjacent}_post_where`. Using this filter with `$adjacent` swapped for either `previous` or `next` you can make the link generator search for posts that are other than `status = publish` in the following way for instance:

```
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_where', function( $query_string ) {

    $new_status_query_string_repl = "(p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'future')";

    $new_query = preg_replace( "/p\.post_status = 'publish'/", $new_status_query_string_repl, $query_string );

    return $new_query;

});
```

Note: didn't test this, might need adjustments. But the hook is there and the query string should be altered to include `future` posts in the adjacent posts queries.

Answer (score 0):

Found perfect solution thanks to David Gard.

```
add_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'my_add_future_posts_to_nav', 3, 99);
add_filter('get_next_post_where', 'my_add_future_posts_to_nav', 3, 99);
function my_add_future_posts_to_nav($where, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms){

return str_replace("p.post_status = 'publish'", "p.post_status IN ('publish', 'future')", $where);

}
```